# Finding two elements in an array of documents that appear in a given order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Let's assume I have the following document structure in database:

```
{ name: String,
  subDocs: [{
    index: Number,
    value: Number
  }]
}
```

So that a typical document looks like:

```
{ name: 'Document 1',
  subDocs: [ 
    { index: 0, value: 30 },
    { index: 1, value: 40 },
    { index: 2, value: 10 },
    { index: 3, value: 20 },
    { index: 4, value: 700 },
    { index: 5, value: 40 }
  ]
}
```

Now, I would like to find all documents which contain subDocs with values A = 10 and B = 40 BUT the occurrence of the items in the array must meet the following requirement A.index < B.index. So basically the item with the value of A must appear earlier in the collection than B. So the object above meets the requirement while this one not, because the values don't appear in the order:

```
{ name: 'Document 2',
  subDocs: [ 
    { index: 0, value: 40 },
    { index: 1, value: 70 },
    { index: 2, value: 10 },
    { index: 3, value: 20 },
    { index: 4, value: 700 }
  ]
}
```

Can we achieve it with Mongoose yet not sacrificing performance of such a query?

Comment: why don't you sort them after you get the docs ?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeBailey. Can you please elaborate more on this idea? I don't think that sorting helps in this case. I also want to have all the job to be done by the MongoDB engine so I don't need to filter it additionally in my backend code.

Comment: object you mentioned contains values other than 10,20 ? your question is a bit unclear sorry :p

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. The field 'value' is an Integer so it can hold any valid integer you can image :)

Comment: _which contain subDocs with values A = 10 and B = 40_ , so, how can this be expected output ? `{ name: 'Some name',
  subDocs: [ 
    { index: 0, value: 30 },
    { index: 1, value: 40 },
    { index: 2, value: 10 },
    { index: 3, value: 20 },
    { index: 4, value: 700 },
    { index: 5, value: 40 }
  ]
}`

Comment: I basically need something like this: `MyDocument.find({ $and: [ { 'subDocs.value': $eq: A }, { 'subDocs.value': $eq: B }, { 'subDocs.index': { $gt: 'subDocs.index' } } ] })` - you know what, maybe I've just answered my question? I'll give this query a try.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeBailey - the expected output is to return whole documents where `subDocs` meet my query. So if I had `Document 1` and `Document 2` in my DB, then only `Document 1` should be returned for A=10 and B=40 as its `subDocs` array meets my condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that sort of constraint in the query, then you basically have two options depending on what your MongoDB version supports:

#### MongoDB 3.6

You would preferably use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ***"in addition"*** to any normal query conditions to actually select valid documents:

```
var A = 10, B = 40;

Model.find({
  "subDocs.value": { "$all": [A, B] },
  "$expr": {
    "$lt": [
      { "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$subDocs.index",
        { "$indexOfArray": [ "$subDocs.value", A ]}
      ]},
      { "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$subDocs.index",
        { "$indexOfArray": [ "$subDocs.value", B ]}  
      ]}
    ]
  }
})
```

Or matching the **"last"** occurrence:

```
Model.find({
  "subDocs.value": { "$all": [A, B] },
  "$expr": {
    "$lt": [
      { "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$subDocs.index",
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [{ "$size": "$subDocs.value" }, 1 ] },
          { "$indexOfArray": [ { "$reverseArray": "$subDocs.value" }, A ] }
        ]}
      ]},
      { "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$subDocs.index",
        { "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [{ "$size": "$subDocs.value" }, 1 ] },
          { "$indexOfArray": [ { "$reverseArray": "$subDocs.value" }, B ] }
        ]}
      ]}
    ]
  }
})
```

#### Earlier Versions

Same thing, but without native operators you need to use the JavaScript evaluation of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```
var A = 10, B = 40;

Model.find({
  "subDocs.value": { "$all": [A, B] },
  "$where": `this.subDocs.find( e => e.value === ${A}).index
      < this.subDocs.find( e => e.value === ${B}).index`
})
```

Or matching the **"last"** occurrence:

```
Model.find({
  "subDocs.value": { "$all": [10,40] },
  "$where": `let arr = this.subDocs.reverse();
      return arr.find( e => e.value === ${A}).index
        > arr.find( e => e.value === ${B}).index`
})
```

If you needed that in an aggregation pipeline, then you would use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) and similar logic to the first example instead:

```
var A = 10, B = 40;

Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "subDocs.value": { "$all": [A, B] } } },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$lt": [
          { "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$subDocs.index",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$subDocs.value", A ]}
          ]},
          { "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$subDocs.index",
            { "$indexOfArray": [ "$subDocs.value", B ]}  
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Suffice to say that the "comparison logic" is not actually native to "query operator expressions" themselves, so the only part that *"optimally"* can be applied to an index is using the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) query operator in all cases. The essential remaining logic actually applies "after" that main expression is evaluated and "in addition to" in order that no results are returned other that those meeting the expression with either [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) or [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

The basic logic of each is essentially to extract the value of the `"index"` property from the "first" array member that actually matches the respective value in the `"value"` property. Where this is "less than", then the condition is `true` and this satisfies the document being returned.

So note that either "calculated evaluation" matches the efficiency of query operators, and without being used "in combination" of other query operator conditions which are able to access an "index", then a "full collection scan" will be initiated.

But the overall result is certainly more efficient than returning all matching items to the first query condition and then rejecting them on the cursor "after" returning from the database.

---

See also documentation for [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/), [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) and [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for JavaScript

Comment: Thank you @Neil Lunn a lot. I think the only thing I need is something which returns the last index of my B-match. Otherwise, if A=10 and B=40 and I have a subDocs collection like: [40, 10, 40] it would not match the document. It's because it will find the 10 as an A, the first (rather then the last) 40 as a B, and the indexes will be A.index > B.index... so no match.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see anything like `$lastIndexOfArray` in Mongoose. Maybe we can somehow reverse the collection in the query before applying the `$indexOfArray` operator (for the B value)?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzkup You do note that I deliberately highlight **"first"** in the body of the answer. This is not a detail in your question, and you really should not do things lilke *" ... but what about if I also need this"* when asking a question. Yes we can `"$reverse"` the array. It's an operator in both MongoDB and JavaScript.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzkup Don't know why I'm doing it but added examples for **last**. Don't ask for any more alterations. If you have a new question then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Hi @Neil Lunn, the "but" statement is not an additional detail. This is something that naturally stems from my original question. I noted it in a comment later as your original query could not catch items having a collection of [40,10,40] where A=10 and B=40, even though it should match it according to the criteria in my original question. So I need to reverse the array only for the second half of the query, I mean for the B part as we need the first index of A and the last index of B. Anyway, thank you a lot for your time and solving my problem :)